# Can Salesforce Platform License Users Approve via Email?

Tags: approval-process, licenses

Looking for confirmation on whether users with the 'Salesforce Platform' license can approve via email.

In the past, I've worked with customers where this worked, but getting an error in one customer's org "An error occurred and your workflow approval message was not processed. Please contact your system administrator."

If I move the user to a full Salesforce license, then the email approval works fined, but not with the 'Salesforce Platform' license.

Users' profile has 'Api enabled' permission fyi.

Comment: Form the description of Doc, it seems 'Salesforce Platform' license can't do this. https://ap.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm

Comment: Salesforce Platform - Designed for users who need access to custom apps but not to standard CRM functionality. Users with this user license are entitled to use custom apps developed in your organization or installed from Force.com AppExchange. In addition, they are entitled to use core platform functionality such as accounts, contacts, reports, dashboards, documents, and custom tabs. However, these users are not entitled to some user permissions and standard apps, including standard tabs and objects such as forecasts and opportunities.

Comment: @JiaHu I don't see what in that description is relevant to approvals. They're a core platform function so this would imply they can.

Comment: @ca_peterson I am not sure about it. Anyway, I will make time to take a test by myself.

Comment: I tested this in a Developer Org. and I can use Salesforce Platform user to approve through the email. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1):

The use case here is that we're working with a customer to implement FinancialForce PSA and configuring approval for a Timecard object via email.

It seems as though I recall we've been able to do email approvals with Salesforce Platform users in the past, because if we shift the user from Salesforce Platform to Salesforce license, then they're able to approve via email.

Comment: I happen to work for FinancialForce and know the owner of your case - it looks like a platform bug from what I've seen, we're bringing it up with them to see what's happening. Based on the test results by @JiaHu this certainly looks like a bug.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I think I heard a rumor it ended up being related to profile configuration?